Puppeteer login with cookies in cloud
I have an issue with logging in to Linkedin using cookies. Here is the code below:

const { default: puppeteer } = require("rebrowser-puppeteer");


const { cookies, userAgent } = customData || {}
const browser = await this.getBrowser()
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });
await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
       
await page.authenticate({ username: proxyAuth?.username, password: proxyAuth?.password })


await page.setCookie(...cookies)

      

This works fine on my local environment but not in production. On my local env, I am able to login without issues.  However, when I deploy to cloud, the cookies works for a while, then stops. I also get logged out of my account on the browser (from where I have copied the cookies used to log in on puppeteer). This doesn't happen when I am in my local env.
Things I have tried:

Used a residential proxy - clean, static residential proxy.
Tried to replicate my local env in cloud - including setting timezone, language, user agent etc. Nothing seems to work.

Here is a cookie sample:
const sampleCookie = [{
    "domain": ".www.linkedin.com",
    "expirationDate": 1747054449.639037,
    "hostOnly": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "li_at",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": null,
    "value": "cookieToken"
}]

Really the only thing that changed between local env and cloud is deploying the script to a VM.
What could I be doing wrong?
Any suggestion on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.
